# Is it possible to write a Tee in Windows batch or in Java?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, command-prompt, tee

I have a Java program that I run in Windows 7 console:

```
java -classpath classfolder mypackage.MyProgram
```

This program runs for very long. Time-by-time it writes output to the console using System.out.println.

Is it possible to direct its output both to the console and into a log file in real-time without modifying the existing Java code?

If Windows 7 is unable to do that, is it possible to write a Tee utility in Java?

Is it solved in Windows 8?

Comment: It is quite possible... In the "logger" program, just read the standard input in a loop (e.g. with [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)), and do what you want to do with it: log it to wherever you want. All you have to do is pipe the output of the first program into the second: `java -classpath classfolder mypackage.MyProgram | java -classpath classfolder mylogger.MyLoggerProgram`

Comment: You can download `tee.exe` for Windows here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/unxutils/current/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name LOL... I failed to Google :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it "without modifying the existing Java code" you could write another wrapper class that reassigns `System.out` appropriately and then calls the existing main class

```
package mypackage;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.output.*;

public class TeeWrapper {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileOutputStream logFile = new FileOutputStream("log.txt");
    try {
      System.setOut(new PrintStream(new TeeOutputStream(System.out, logFile)));
      MyProgram.main(args);
    } finally {
      logFile.close();
    }
  }
}
```

(using [TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) from Apache commons-io).

You run the wrapper instead of the original class

```
java -classpath classfolder mypackage.TeeWrapper
```

Answer (score 4):

The `tee` command could help you but it is an Unix command. You can use [this batch file](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/tee_nt.txt) as analog of `tee`.

Example:

```
systeminfo | tee_nt.bat 1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, just read from system.in and output both to system.out and a file.