# How to make a windows command output to be displayed on console and to write into a file at the same time

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Thanks for looking into my question.

I have a batch command running in jenkins windows batch command prompt. Let's a take a simple command

```
echo hello world
```

I want to write this command output to a file as well as this output to be displayed on command prompt. I have tried below 2 ways.

```
echo helloworld |tee -a .\test.log
echo hello world >>.\test.log >>CON
```

both of the above are not working.

Could anyone help me with this.

Thanks,
R Dama.

Comment: [here's](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5386) native windows script (not binary) that emulates tee command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying Windows command prompt output and redirecting it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file)

Comment: Also related: [Using a custom Tee command for .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711839) and [Is it possible to write a Tee in Windows batch or in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14278504)

Answer (score 2):

There is no `tee` command in pure batch scripting.

The easiest work-around is to redirect to a file and then to type the file, like this (do not put a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> behind the `echo` command as it was output also):

```cmd
echo Hello world!> "logfile.txt"
type "logfile.txt"
```

Of course, the output is only printed to the console as soon as the command (`echo` in the example) has been finished executing.

If you want to append to an already existing log file `logfile.txt`, use this instead:

```cmd
echo Hello world!> "logfile.tmp"
type "logfile.tmp"
type "logfile.tmp" >> "logfile.txt"
del "logfile.tmp"
```

Alternatively, in case `logfile.txt` does for sure exist, you may use this:

```cmd
echo Hello world!> "logfile.tmp"
type "logfile.tmp"
copy /Y "logfile.txt" + "logfile.tmp" "logfile.txt" /B > nul
del "logfile.tmp"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this with PowerShell:

```
powershell "echo HelloWorld | tee test.txt"
```

Another way, without PowerShell, could be to type the file that received the output:

```
echo HelloWorld > test.txt | type test.txt
```

I do prefer the first solution...

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I could not use "type test.log". Because, i have appended 500+lines to this test.log. I don't want to print all these lines.

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not really have a `tee` command short of the PowerShell `Tee-Object` (alias `tee`). Here is a cmd script subroutine that will produce a `tee` effect. The `DoMsg` subroutine will append everything to the log file and then write it to stdout.

```
@ECHO OFF
CALL:DoMsg ECHO hello, world
CALL:DoCmd DIR
EXIT /B 0

:DoMsg
ECHO %* >"%TEMP%\domsg.tmp"
TYPE "%TEMP%\domsg.tmp" >>test.log
TYPE "%TEMP%\domsg.tmp"
GOTO:EOF

:DoCmd
CALL:DoMsg CMD: %*
%*
GOTO:EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. 
I believe this should work. Will try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need it to do both in real time, you could use 2 separate commands:

```
echo hello world > test.log
type test.log
```

Which could also be done in a single line:

```
echo hello world > test.log & type test.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the response isrnick.

I could not use "type test.log".  Because, i have appended 500+lines to this test.log. I don't want to print all these lines.